# Login widget animates another widget with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, authentication, jquery-animate

**EDITED : i opened a new question because i see that i will need a php code instead of jquery : [Add echo to my wordpress sidebar for non-connected users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328278/add-echo-to-my-wordpress-sidebar-for-non-connected-users)**

---

i use Nice Login Widget for connection in my WordPress test website. Unfortunately the login widget does not have "Inscription" link, so i made a link in a text widget just under the login widget. The problem is that this link is not syncronized with the login widget and it is visible even when a member is connected and when he is online. I would like to make the "Inscription" link invisible when someone is connected.

I use jQuery which does not work in my case, because when the login widget refreshes the page, the jQuery effect does not kept but the css gets priority... pls see the demo here : http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/ - you can connect yourself with username : testing / password : testing2014

The CSS

```
/* this is the text widget with the "Inscription" link */
#text-7 {
opacity: 1;
}
```

The script

```
    // when the "Login" button is loaded and clicked, Inscription link is invisible 
    jQuery('.sp-widget-login-div form p input').load(function(){
        jQuery('#text-7').animate({'opacity':0},500,'easeInCirc');
    });
    jQuery('.sp-widget-login-div form p input').click(function(){
        jQuery('#text-7').animate({'opacity':0},500,'easeInCirc');
    });

    // when the "Logout" link is loaded and clicked, Inscription link is visible
    jQuery('.logout-link').load(function(){
        jQuery('#text-7').animate({'opacity':1},500,'easeInCirc');
    });
    jQuery('.logout-link').click(function(){
        jQuery('#text-7').animate({'opacity':1},500,'easeInCirc');
    });
```

Thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 0):

use the is_user_logged_in() function to show or hide the link.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   echo '<a href="#">Your link</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will come back to say if it works... i have never heared about this function... but i must add this to which element ?

Comment: I am sorry, i am not smart enough to use this... i tried : 
`if (is_user_logged_out()) {
   jQuery('#text-7').animate({'opacity':1},500,'easeInCirc');
   jQuery('#text-7').echo '<a href="http://www.vihegay.com/register/">Inscription</a>';
  }else {
   jQuery('#text-7').animate({'opacity':0},500,'easeInCirc');
   jQuery('#text-7').remove();
  }`

Comment: Ok, you need that the inscription link appear if user is not logged in and disappear if he is, right?, if so, then you need to use this function and no need to use javascript

Comment: yes, it is right, i need the link to be appeared when user is NOT logged in. 
so, the code you gave me is not even jquery ? is this code php ? unfortunately i do not know anything about it... do i put your code where exactly ?

Comment: yes it's PHP, you need to add in your template where you want the link is shown.

Comment: i can not put it on a page, it must be exactly under my login widget... how can i put this code in a text widget via the admin panel ? i guess i need some php codes before and after as the text widget is a simple HTML...

Comment: Sorry, but to do that, you need to know a little about html and php

Comment: And if i put a php code in the sidebar.php, something like "if is_user_logged_in", #text-7 widget is invisible, else visible", is it possible ?

Comment: So i asked a new question here for the php : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328278/add-echo-to-my-wordpress-sidebar-for-non-connected-users and thanks a lot !