# Add echo to my wordpress sidebar for non-connected users

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, sidebar

i have Nice Login Widget which does not have any link to the registration page for non-members (simple visitors). I would like to visualize the `Inscription` link on the sidebar, just under the login widget but NOT anymore when someone is logged in !

The idea is that i will visualize the link with `echo` and by its css i could position it absolute.

I do not know anything about php, i tried to add some codes in my `sidebar.ph`p file but it does not work :

The `sidebar.php` is a classic `twentyeleven` theme :

```
<?php

if ( 'content' != $current_layout ) :
?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

                <?php
                    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                        echo '';
                    else
                        echo '<a class="inscrip-link" href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/register/">Inscription</a>';
                ?>

                <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'vihegay' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

                <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'vihegay' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_register(); ?>
                        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

My added codes in above codes are :

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '';
    else
        echo '<a class="inscrip-link" href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/register/">Inscription</a>';
?>
```

Then i would add the css to the link class `inscrip-link` :

```
.inscrip-link {
position:absolute;
top:300px;
left: 30%;
z-index:1;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do this ? (I accept better solution as well !:))

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be missing a few curly brackets.

```
<?php
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {
        echo '<a class="inscrip-link" href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/register/">Inscription</a>';
    }
?>
```

I have changed your code a bit. The register link will **only** show when a user is not logged in.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! In the meantime i found another solution which is better than this one because at this case i must add the link to the page with an absolute position, however, my most important goal was to add it precisely under the login widget and with absolute position ii is difficult because of other below existing widgets. I gave you a point and thanks a lot again !

Comment: @IgorLaszlo, no problem, feel free to write your own solution as an answer (and mark it as correct) so others who have the same problem as you will know how you solved it.

Comment: Curly brackets are not necessary for a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a better solution for my case to be able to add my link with relative position to the sidebar... if someone has the same problem :

- I added a text widget with my inscription link (#text-7) under my login widget.
- In sidebar.php I added a widget with the same id (#text-7) which gives a classe to the body when users are logged-in (see php codes below).
- In the style.css i give style to the #text-7 widget and i display:none when the body class is "logged-in" (see codes below).

PHP

```
        <aside <?php echo (is_user_logged_in() ? 'class="widget widget_text logged-in"' : ''); ?> id="text-7" class="widget">
            <h3 class="widget-title"></h3>
            <div class="center"><a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/register/">Inscription</a></div>
        </aside>
```

CSS

```
#text-7 {position:relative;margin: -50px auto 30px;z-index:1;}
.logged-in #text-7 {display: none;}
```

Together with my personal class, i also added all other classes to the widget what a widget should have (widget and widget_text) because if not, it did not work for me... maybe it is just a "handmade" code but it work fine !